# My simple Spring Boot app isn't returning the webpage

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

When I send the GET request to the mapping "/", I receive NotFound errors.

*Here is my @**Controller*** class:

```
@Controller
public class Store {
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }

}
```

*Here is my **application.properties*** file which specifies the location of the view files:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

*And for reference, here is my **home.html** file:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Store</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

*My home.html file is in the view folder within the webapp folder.*

To my understanding when sending the request to localhost:8080 the home page should load, I am perplexed that it is not the case.

Any help at all will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE**:

So I managed to get it working by renaming the HTML file from *home.html* to *index.html* and moving it to the webapp folder. How is it now working after I rename it and move it to the base web folder???? Surely the name is irrelevant and I already specified the prefix and suffix to act as the view resolver to point to the directory of the view files.

This is working due to Springs default behaviour of mapping our index.html page as the landing page, but the method handler is still never called...

**FINAL UPDATE:**

I have recreated this project in Eclipse (previously created in STS4) and it is working, there was no change needed. I assume it was due to my configuration of STS4. So to anyone that may experience this issue in the future or something similar, double check your configuration of your IDE, it may not always be your code. :)

Thank you all for your input.

Comment: You could try adding thymeleaf dependency in pom.xml and then try...basically check if you have a view resolver

Comment: (1) `home.html`  , your code use  `/body>`  , it should be </body> (2) Your code is OK. Nothig Wrong. I am not change anything. It all ok. (3) `curl http://localhost:8080` , return home.html content.

Comment: @life888888 Yeah thanks for pointing out me mistake in the markup, i figured that might be the reason because it wouldn't compile, but even after fixing it, it didn't work... i am so lost as to why, everything points to it working.

Comment: @GlennQuagmire Believe it or not, but its already added on my pom.xml, this is making me lose hair....

Comment: you could try changing the request mapping and see, by default the path is "/" and you have explicitly mentioned mapping as "/". for your method maybe change it to something else like "/test" and try.

Comment: @GlennQuagmire I did, i added an entirely different handler with the mapping “/home” and nothing. I also tried creating a new project, and this time storing the HTML file in the template folder where Spring Boot auto-defaults to, and nothing. 404s everywhere. I believe it may not even be entering the mapping method for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few things to look into:

1. Check that your home.html file is in the correct folder. In your application.properties file, you specified that the view files are in the "/view/" folder within the webapp folder. As a result, ensure that your home.html file is in the "/webapp/view/" folder.
2. Check to see if your application is set up correctly to serve static resources. If not, add the line below to your application. file with properties:

```
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/META-INF/resources/,classpath:/resources/,classpath:/static/,classpath:/public/
```

This configuration ensures that your application serves static resources from the locations specified.

3. If you're still having problems, try modifying your home method to return the full path to the home.html file, as shown below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home() {
return "/view/home.html";
}
```

This should make it possible for your application to find the home.html file.

Comment: I tried all your of your solutions and they didn't work. But that's the thing, they should have, even the base application SHOULD have worked, I'm not sure if its a new version of Boot's configuration but it just doesn't work, when i added the lines you suggested in my application.config, the console started displaying the message, "No mapping for GET /". But that just cant be true right?

Comment: Replace @RequestMapping with @GetMapping and try again it will look something like this `@GetMapping("/")`

Comment: Yeah I tried that too,  not sure what is going wrong, going to try to add all the other Spring Dependencies in an attempt to solve it.